# How to Store and retrieve data in internal storage of android

Tags: java, android-studio

**REGISTRATION FORM:**
**USERNAME:** username
**FULL NAME:** enter full name
**PASSWORD:** enter password
**CONFIRM PASSWORD:** enter confirm password

All user registration data store in encrypted format in internal storage of file.

**LOGIN FORM:**
**USERNAME:** enter username
**PASSWORD:** enter password

Check data from file if exists then login otherwise show message username and password incorrect.

Comment: you can use sqlite db or sharedpreferences for that

Comment: use sharedpreferences for that. easy way